# How do I show the resulting image after a php upload?

Tags: php, forms, upload, image-uploading

I'm trying to display the uploaded image and it's url after it has been processed using this code but I'm a bit stuck on how I would achieve this instead of the page returning with "done..."

http://llngg6czd-site.1tempurl.com/tester/index.php

Index.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Upload Files using normal form and PHP</title>
</head>
<body>
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="upload_image.php">
<div class="row">
<label for="image">Select a File to Upload</label><br />
<input type="file" name="image" /> 
</div>
<div class="row">
<input type="submit" value="Upload" />
</div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

image_upload.php

```
<?php
require_once('ImageManipulator.php');
if ($_FILES['image']['error'] > 0) {
echo "Error: " . $_FILES['image']['error'] . "<br />";
} else {
// array of valid extensions
$validExtensions = array('.jpg', '.jpeg', '.gif', '.png');
// get extension of the uploaded file
$fileExtension = strrchr($_FILES['image']['name'], ".");
// check if file Extension is on the list of allowed ones
if (in_array($fileExtension, $validExtensions)) {
$newNamePrefix = time() . '_';
$manipulator = new ImageManipulator($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']);
// resizing to 200x200
$newImage = $manipulator->resample(200, 200);
// saving file to uploads folder
$manipulator->save('uploads/' . $newNamePrefix . $_FILES['image']['name']);
echo 'Done ...';
} else {
echo 'You must upload an image...';
}
}
```

Imagemanipulator.php

```
https://gist.github.com/philBrown/880506
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You save the file as

```
'uploads/' . $newNamePrefix . $_FILES['image']['name']
```

Therefor you can simply show it by giving back an IMG-Tag with the 'src' attribute:

```
echo '<img src="./uploads/' . $newNamePrefix . $_FILES['image']['name'] . '">';
```